# cutomize ion-datetime calendar in ionic 6

Tags: css, datetime, ionic6

How to change font size for calendar days, colour for selected date. Not able to customise calendar for selecting date. Also styles are different for both android and ios which creates so much confusion to users and there is n way to customise it

Answer (score 0):

you can write this to change color:

```
`ion-datetime { --ion-color-primary: 'whatever color you want'}`
```

--ion-color-primary is the color for selected date by default.